# Joining parents in 2 tables on exact match of child row values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have 2 table with below structure :

Table 1 (Tb1) :

```
MasId Int, ItemId int, Quantity int
1          1           10
1          2           5
1          3           18
2          2           3
2          4           8
```

Table 2 (Tb2) :

```
MasId Int, ItemId int, Quantity int
10          1           10
10          2           5
10          3           18
6           2           3
6           4           8
```

I want to match Tb1 with Tb2 with `ItemId` and `Quantity` Columns. and get below query :

```
Tb1.MasId   Tb2.MasId
1           10
2           6
```

Table1 and Table2 contain about 2000000 record. and I use `SQL Server 2012`

**EDIT 1**

In Tb1 and Tb2 exists records such below :

Tb1:

```
MasId, ItemId, Quantity
3      15       10
3      16       2
```

Tb2:

```
MasId, ItemId, Quantity
20     15      10
20     18      5
```

Tb1.MasId and Tb2.MasId is not matched together.

Comment: Note: The selected answer gives wrong data in some cases. Please see my comment on it, and my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query [available as a SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9244c/9) returns correct results even with tricky data:

```
SELECT
   Tb1MasId = A1.MasId,
   Tb2MasId = B1.MasId
FROM
   (
      SELECT
         MasID,
         Pattern = Checksum_Agg(Binary_Checksum(ItemId, Quantity))
      FROM dbo.Tb1
      GROUP BY MasId
   ) A1
   INNER JOIN (
      SELECT
         MasID,
         Pattern = Checksum_Agg(Binary_Checksum(ItemId, Quantity))
      FROM dbo.Tb2
      GROUP BY MasId
   ) B1
      ON A1.Pattern = B1.Pattern
      AND NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT * 
         FROM
            (
               SELECT A2.ItemID, A2.Quantity
               FROM dbo.Tb1 A2
               WHERE A1.MasID = A2.MasID
               UNION ALL
               SELECT B2.ItemID, B2.Quantity
               FROM dbo.Tb2 B2
               WHERE B1.MasId = B2.MasID
            ) X
         GROUP BY ItemID, Quantity
         HAVING Count(*) = 1
      );
```

The other answers on the page give incorrect results with the sample data in [my SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9244c/9). Specifically, adding the following data to `Tb2` will break [X.L.Ant's current query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13968114/57611) (which will show a false match `2, 8` due to not detecting that the `8, 3, 18` doesn't belong).

```
INSERT dbo.Tb2
VALUES
   (7, 1, 10),
   (7, 2, 5),
   (7, 3, 17),
   (8, 3, 18),
   (8, 2, 3),
   (8, 4, 8);
```

Comment: Tb1 and Tb2 have about 1000000 rows. and your query is very slow. can I have a query with better performance.

Comment: Maybe. Let me think. Some idea of your data characteristics and indexes is essential. How many itemids per MasId? How many potential mismatches are there on average (matching rows that are not part of a full match)? How many bytes are in each row of your tables? Is there a parent MasId table or tables? I may be good at Sql but I am not a magician and need a lot more information. How many distinct MasIds in both tables? How many output rows from my query?

Comment: **Update**: I have 2 new versions for you in [this SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9244c/9). They are still the same fundamental method but have some optimizations which should make a *huge* difference on 1,000,000 rows. It appears the 2nd query may be best, but I don't have data anything close to yours to test on. I *still* need answers to my questions so I can set up a reasonable test case that somewhat resembles your data. I have another idea for this that I'd like to explore, but doing so is kind of pointless without data to test.

Comment: Thanks! How long does it take to run? Any chance on getting some realistic test data?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
SELECT Tb1.MasId AS MasId1, Tb2.MasId AS MasId2
FROM Tb1, Tb2, (SELECT MasId, COUNT(MasId) AS Cnt FROM Tb1 GROUP BY MasId) Cnt
WHERE Tb1.ItemId = Tb2.ItemId
  AND Tb1.Quantity = Tb2.Quantity
  AND Tb1.MasId = Cnt.MasId
GROUP BY Tb1.MasId, Tb2.MasId, Cnt.Cnt
HAVING COUNT(Tb1.MasId) = Cnt.Cnt
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b3119/11/0)

Comment: Please see **Edit1**. with your query can't matched data correctly.

Comment: Ok, but how do you want to handle 3,16,2 and 20,18,5 if no match exist in the other table ? Do you want them to appear in your result or not ?

Comment: I want to see only all matched records.

Comment: So the query I mentioned works. It will only show masid from records for which itemid and quantity are the same in both tables, and exclude records that don't.

Comment: Unless you want that ALL of rows for each MasId match.

Comment: please check your query. in result of query in `SQLFiddle` must be matched (TbMasid1, TbMasid2)(2,2).

Comment: I use `SQL Server 2012`. please change `My SQL 5.5.28` to `SQL Server 2012` in SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Oops, yeah you're right. I corrected. Weird that behavior is so different between DB engines.

Comment: Could we please, please, in almost **2013** for crying out loud, use ANSI style JOINs?!?!

Comment: Also, please see your [updated fiddle with trickier data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5be5d/4) showing that your query can return the wrong result--I only changed the data, not the query.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do group by like below

```
SELECT Tb1.MasId, Tb2.MasId
       FROM Tb1 
          INNER JOIN Tb2 
             ON Tb1.ItemId = Tb2.ItemId
             AND Tb1.Quantity = Tb2.Quantity
 group by Tb1.MasId, Tb2.MasId
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not going to provide a correct answer.